# Тестирование потоков и перехват исключений в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, исключения, тестирование

Мы тестируем код и знаем, что у нас должно вывалиться исключение. К примеру мы тестируем итератор и знаем, что больше элементов нету и если мы вызовем `next ()`, тогда получим `NoSuchElementException`, и чтобы всё было нормально мы пишем:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void shoulThrowNoSuchElementException() {
     it = new Iteratorrmatrixmass(new int[][]{});
     it.next();
}
```

У нас есть несколько потоков и один из потоков должен выбросить исключение `OptimisticException`:

```
@Test (expected = OptimisticException.class)
    public void update() throws InterruptedException {
        Base base = new Base(1, 1, "12321");
        Base base1 = new Base(1, 2, "");
        СacheBase data = new СacheBase();
        data.add(base);
        Thread r1 = new Thread(new Update(data, base1), "r1");
        Thread r2 = new Thread(new Update(data, base1), "r2"); // здесь должна быть OptimisticException.class
        r1.start();
        r2.start();
        r1.join();
        r2.join();
        System.out.println(base.getVersion());
    }
```

Но в этом случае (`expected = OptimisticException.class`) эта надпись нам не помогла, в консоли всё равно вылазит надпись:

> Exception in thread "r2" ru.job4j.blockhash.OptimisticException: Объект уже обновлён до текущей версии, в обновлении отказано

Я полагаю из-за того, что это исключение выскакивает не в основном потоке. Что сделать чтобы тестирование прошло успешно?

Comment: А может просто создать один поток, а второй считать мэйном? и сделать так, чтобы именно мэйн выбрасывал исключение. Также можно сделать executor service и коммитить таски в него, потом брать результат этих тасок и если в результате возбудится исключение, то оно пробросится наверх.

Comment: А через mock не получится обработать исключение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой "костыльный", но рабочий вариант :

```
    @Test
    public void test() {

    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        throw new OptimisticException("Optimistic Exception"); // ваш runnable код
    });

    assertThatThrownBy(future::get)
            .hasCauseExactlyInstanceOf(OptimisticException.class)
            .hasMessageContaining("Optimistic Exception");
   }
```

Как это работает :

Создается лямбда, которая выполняется когда вызывается метод get. Затем перехватывается ошибка и из нее достается исключение, которое выкинулось в вашем коде.

P.S библиотека для ассертов - AssertJ

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы тест выполнился вам надо бросить исключение в текущем потоке. Чтобы обработать исключение, возникающее в потоках надо в основном потоке установить обработчик

```
Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
   throw new OptimisticException(e);        
});
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?